# Выполнить поиск в memo по начальным символам и удалить эти строки?

Tags: delphi

В общем суть такая, что в мемо текст такого типа:

```
11111111232515311
11111111843448448
11111111846998995
```

т.е. начало одинаковое, как мне найти и удалить эти строки? (кол-во символов в каждой строке различно)

Comment: А кол-во единиц в начале известно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно удалить те строки, где спереди встречается 11111111 или удалить эти единицы из каждой строки ?
1-й вариант:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var deleteString: boolean;
    i, j:integer;
begin
  deleteString:=false;
  i:=0;
  while i<>(Memo1.Lines.Count-1) do
  begin
    for j:=0 to 8 do
    begin
      if copy(Memo1.Lines[i], j, 1)='1' then
        deleteString:=true
      else
      begin
        deleteString:=false;
        break;
      end;
    end;
    if deleteString=true then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Delete(i);
      i:=i-1;
    end;
    i:=i+1;
  end;
end;
```

2-й вариант:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var deleteString: boolean;
    i, j:integer;
begin
  deleteString:=false;
  for i:=0 to (Memo1.Lines.Count-1) do
  begin
    for j:=0 to 8 do
    begin
      if copy(Memo1.Lines[i], j, 1)='1' then
        deleteString:=true
      else
      begin
        deleteString:=false;
        break;
      end;
    end;
    if deleteString=true then
      Memo1.Lines[i]:=copy(Memo1.Lines[i], 9, length(Memo1.Lines[i])-9);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Первый вариант - дибилизм =) Можно было просто отыскать в строке подстроку "11111111"(8 единиц) и если найдено вхождение, то удалить строку...а что вы написали за ерунду?

Comment: Эх, давно я Delphi учил. Не помню про подстроки. Ну всего-то одним циклом меньше станет :)
Главное - РАБОТАЕТ :)

Comment: Ну здесь даже проблема не в знаниях, а в логике =)

Answer (score 0):

[Работа со строками в помощь](http://www.delphi-manual.ru/work-with-strings.php), а именно:

> `функция Pos(Substr: String; Str: String): Integer
> Возвращает позицию (индекс) первого вхождения Substr в строке Str. Если Substr нет в Str, возвращает 0.`

```
procedure TForm1.DeleteStrings;
var
  i: integer;
  str: string;
begin
  i:= 0;
  repeat
    begin
      if self.FindString(Copy(Memo1.Lines[i], 1, 8)) then
        Memo1.Lines.Delete(i)
      else
        inc(i);
    end;
  until i = Memo1.Lines.Count - 1;
end;

function TForm1.FindString(str: string): boolean;
const
  MyString: string = '11111111';
begin
  if Pos(MyString, str) = 1 then
    result:= true
  else
    result:= False;
end;
```